# Plotting a convex hull with a coordinate mesh

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am plotting the convex hull of some curves by extracting the curves from a contour plot and constructing the convex hull around their discretized version . It's not terribly accurate for calculations but it works well for a quick visualization.

Here's a simple example.

```
curve = ContourPlot3D[{((x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2 + (z - 
     0.5)^2) ((x + 0.5)^2 + (y + 0.5)^2 + (z + 0.5)^2) == 2,
     x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1},
     {z, -1.1, 1.1}, ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> 0, 
     BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {Blue, Thickness[0.015]}},
     PlotPoints -> 30];

hull = ConvexHullMesh@MeshCoordinates@Quiet@DiscretizeGraphics@First@Normal@curve;

Show[curve,hull]
```

The result is a convex hull with a mesh of all the polygons:

[image: Convex hull]

Can I turn this into an object that I can display a normal, coordinate-based mesh on? Something like this

[image: Mesh example]

that would work for any convex hull.

I want to do this because the convex hull mesh is ugly, but if I remove it it becomes difficult to see where a convex hull bends, where it's round etc.

Comment: what about `hull["Graphics3D"]`?

Comment: @RunnyKine Hm. That doesn't seem to accept any options related to the mesh, unfortunately.

Comment: @RunnyKine I have added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a `MeshRegion`, so you can plot it with `RegionPlot3D`,

Of course, since your cylinder is rotated with respect to the cartesian coordinates, you'll need to find the right combination of coordinates to give the mesh you want.

Here are some examples,

```
RegionPlot3D[hull, Mesh -> 10, MeshFunctions -> #, Axes -> True, 
   ImageSize -> 400] & /@ 
      {{#1 &, #2 &}, 
       {1/4 (2 - Sqrt[2]) #1 + 1/4 (2 + Sqrt[2]) #2 - #3/2 &,
        -(#1/2) + #2/2 + #3/Sqrt[2] &},
       {1/4 (2 + Sqrt[2]) #1 + 1/4 (2 - Sqrt[2]) #2 &,
        1/4 (2 - Sqrt[2]) #1 + 1/4 (2 + Sqrt[2]) #2 &, 
        -(#1/2) + #2/2 &}, 
       {1/4 (2 + Sqrt[2]) #1 + 1/4 (2 - Sqrt[2]) #2 + #3/2 &,
        -(#1/2) + #2/2 + #3/Sqrt[2] &}}
```

[image]

This set of coordinates comes close to matching the original mesh,

```
RegionPlot3D[hull, Mesh -> 15, 
 MeshFunctions -> {(1/Sqrt[2.] (#1 - #2) &), (1/Sqrt[
      2.] (-#1 + #3) &), 1/Sqrt[3] (#1 + #2 + #3) &},
 Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]